# create a regex used with jQuery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am using [jquery validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org) for my web form an need to validate a text field that is validated with the following.

- 1: Must include a number.
- 2: the letters 'a' 'A' or 'b' 'B' are allowed after the number.
- 3: the above letters with out a number before them are not allowed.

Examples:

`1, 25, 15a, 45B, 2A, 53b, 96` - are allowed

`A, a, B, b, B76, a34,` - not allowed

This is for the entry of the numbering of flats/appartments in a block where sometimes a number has both an `*a(A)` and a `*b(B)`.

Ive currently got this additional method which allows numbers and letters.

```
$.validator.addMethod("loginRegex", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(value);
   }, "Username must contain only letters, numbers, or dashes.");
```

But I need it more specific to the requirements above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `/^\d+[a-z]*$/i.test(value)`, or if there can only be 1 letter, `/^\d+[a-z]?$/i`

Comment: Steve, any feedback? What are your exact rules? Why do you have `-` in the regex?

Comment: sorry @Wiktor Stribizew the dash should have been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[0-9][0-9abAB]*$
```

This RegEx seems to work on and matches all examples and criteria provided as shown in this [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/VLYQaw/1)

**Edit: To accommodate what may be a more complex desire, [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/VLYQaw/2) RegEx allows only 1 letter at the end of a string of numbers, while [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/EErlxn/1) RegEx allows 1-3 numbers followed by a letter**

Comment: yep yep @Nope Nope !

Comment: @SteveJoiner Does it mean you want `1abbbaa434` to match?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew While he does not include this as a requirement, I do believe not allowing such input may be the desired effect. As such, I have updated my answer to account for this, if that is what he requires.